# Powershell : Object list to JSON

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Is there a way to convert object list into JSON.

I am able to convert a single object into JSON using the following code

```
 $JsonObject=  ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $item
```

But, I have a list of objects like this

[image: Objects]

I want to convert all objects inside $AllItems into one JSON

Comment: Please tell us what `$AllItems[0].GetType()` reveals. Is that a PSObject, a String or..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a couple of Google searches yielded this info:

- [Creating an array of objects](https://www.varonis.com/blog/powershell-array/#:%7E:text=Creating%20an%20Array%20of%20Objects)
- [ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.1)

`example.ps1`:

```powershell
$data = @(
  [pscustomobject]@{FirstName='Kevin';LastName='Marquette'}
  [pscustomobject]@{FirstName='John'; LastName='Doe'}
)

$json = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $data -Compress

$json
```

```
PS C:\examples> .\example.ps1
[{"FirstName":"Kevin","LastName":"Marquette"},{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}]
```